# Problem with app validation - SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation, validation-list-items

I have a very simple validation script , which compares a date added to the created date and if there is 6months after then it will NOT show an error but if it is before 6months after the created date then it will complain.. It works once, but when you edit that column it just errors no matter what you enter :

```
=IF(TAtestColumn>DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created)+6,DAY(Created)),TRUE)
```

So first time around if the date is 6 months in the future it works , but editing the list item afterwards the formula does not work

Any ideas ?

Comment: sorry I badly read the problem.  so if you edit the item the formula value doesnt refresh?

Comment: sure if you edit the item the error appears evenrthough it shouldn't. so if you put in 6 months today on the new item, and then you edit the item and one day to it, so 23rd august - it errors even though the date is valid

Comment: anyone has any ideas ?? Its driving me insane !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a calculated column of 'Created' and set that to Date only - and use that in the formula.